# How to run bokeh server on a remote host?

Tags: python, bokeh, remote-server

I am currently trying to run a python file on a remote server.
In my local machine I can just ran the command:
    bokeh serve --show myApp.py

However, on my remote host, when I ran bokeh serve, the error message "bokeh: command not found" was shown. I tried pip install bokeh, and finished installation, however, still bokeh command is not found.

Comment: did you install bokeh in the remote server

Comment: Yes I did, I used "pip install bokeh" on the remote server.

Comment: try this on your local & remote machines and post the results   sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])